# How to extend div so that it covers top to bottom

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make some bar signals to signify different components. I want to make the bar so that it covers the whole height of the text, no matter how many lines there are. How can I make so that the bar extends from the top to the bottom of the div?

Divider with a set height:

```css
      .divider {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 20px;
        width: 3px;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 30px;
        background: #0099ff;
        margin-left: 35px;
      }
            p {
      margin-left: 5px;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: var(--font-color);
      }
```

```html
                  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; ">
                    <div class="divider"></div><p>Messages</p>
                   </div>
                   <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-top: -20px; ">
                    <div class="divider"></div><p>Messages <br> Test</p>
                   </div>
```

Divider with height set at 100%:

```css
            .divider {
              display: inline-block;
              height: 100%;
              width: 3px;
              position: relative;
              border-radius: 30px;
              background: #0099ff;
              margin-left: 35px;
            }
                  p {
      margin-left: 5px;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: var(--font-color);
      }
```

```html
                 <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; ">
                    <div class="divider"></div><p>Messages</p>
                   </div>
                   <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-top: -20px; ">
                    <div class="divider"></div><p>Messages <br> google</p>
                   </div>
```

Comment: Well, I don't know whether it is this is according to your requirements or not, but if you apply a `border-left` on the p tag itself, the line to the left will stretch till the whole height of your paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `border-left` on the `p` itself?

```
p {
  border-left:6px solid #0099ff;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--font-color);
}
```

```css
p {
  border-left:6px solid #0099ff;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--font-color);
}
```

```html
                  <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; ">
                    <div class="divider"></div><p>Messages</p>
                   </div>
                   <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-top: -20px; ">
                    <div class="divider"></div><p>Messages <br> Testd
                     asd
                     as<br>dsadasdas
                     as<br>dsadasdas
                     as<br>dsadasdas
                     as<br>dsadasdas
                     </p>
                   </div>
```

Comment: How can you make it so that the border-left has a radius?

Comment: you can do this with SVG, but I do not think you can round this border with clean CSS. There could be some hack-arounds.. which are not clean.

Answer (score 1):

you should set 'divider' to <p> tag and set its class to height '100%'.

```
<p class="divider2">Messages <br> Test</p>

      .divider2 {
    height:100%;
    width: 3px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: #0099ff;
    margin-left: 35px;
  }
```

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/redpeaks/0nm29f3j/27/)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use min-height:100% instead of height:100% in .divider